# Is "Irish potatoes are not boiled twice" a valid proverb?

Tags: proverbs

This "proverb" was used 40 years ago in my dad's school by an English teacher.

My dad says his teacher used it to mean, "Instructions will not be repeated". For example, if a student asked repeatedly,"Do we have to write our answers in full sentences, or in phrases?", the teacher can reply,"Irish potatoes are not boiled twice", meaning that  "I have already told you what to do once and I won't repeat my instructions again"

So anyway, I surfed the internet, and found basically zero results on this supposed "proverb". Is this even a valid proverb that can be used?

[by the way it is probably a reference to the potato famine in Ireland where people lived in abject poverty]

Comment: A more established proverb is “***I don't boil my cabbage twice***”, which may have inspired the Irish version: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+don%27t+boil+my+cabbage+twice

Comment: @user66974: "***There's no use boiling your cabbage twice***" is an established [***Irish*** proverb](https://www.google.com/search?q=there%27s+no+use+boiling+your+cabbage+twice+meaning)

Comment: @Justin - well….the “potato” version is probably just a variant.

Comment: As a subjective answer, (1) "I have never heard either the potato or the cabbage versions" but then I am not Irish and I live in the UK. (2) I would not have guessed the meaning.

Comment: Reasonable research here includes checking the internet for the expression. I find two hits on Google ... and they're both from this thread. A proverb must have a reasonable currency. So _Irish potatoes are not boiled twice_ isn't a proverb. It's grammatical though,  and you're free to use the expression ... but don't assume that your audience will guess the intended meaning correctly.

Comment: As a Irish person, I will add that I’ve never heard that idiom about potatoes not being boiled twice. Though to be fair, I’ve never heard the one from @Justin about cabbage either!  The cabbage one feels dated.

Comment: In Italian, the wry way to decline repeating (usually something that went over well, like a parlor trick) is with the expression *Paganini non ripete*, which dates to a [famous performance](https://www.wordsense.eu/Paganini_non_ripete/) by the violin virtuoso.